# XSLT1 Transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, muenchian-grouping

I would need to transform this input XML:

```
<Log1>
    <Connection User="Peter" Host="Computer01" Port="22"/>
    <Connection User="Peter" Host="Computer02" Port="22"/>
    <Connection User="Peter" Host="Computer02" Port="80"/>
    <Connection User="David" Host="Computer01" Port="8080"/>
    <Connection User="David" Host="Computer01" Port="8080"/>
    <Connection User="David" Host="Computer01" Port="8080"/>
    <Connection User="David" Host="Computer03" Port="22"/>
    <Connection User="David" Host="Computer04" Port="21"/>
</Log1>
```

Into that output XML:

```
<Log2>
    <Event Name="David" Target="Computer01|Computer03|Computer04"/>
    <Event Name="Peter" Target="Computer01|Computer02"/>            
</Log2>
```

So far, I used the Muenchian grouping and obtained something like:

```
<Log2>      
    <Event Name="David" Target="Computer01|Computer01|Computer01|Computer03|Computer04"/>   
    <Event Name="Peter" Target="Computer01|Computer02|computer02"/>
</Log2>
```

The problem is that I cannot get rid of the duplicate machines in my output.

Here is my XSLT:

```
<xsl:key name="myKey" match="Connection" use="@User"/>
<xsl:variable name="separator" select="'|'"/>

<xsl:template match="Log1"> 
    <xsl:element name="Log2">       
        <xsl:for-each select="Connection[count(. | key('myKey', @User)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:sort select="@User" />
            <xsl:element name="Event">
                <xsl:attribute name="Name">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@User" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="Target">
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('myKey', @User)">
                        <xsl:sort select="@Host" />
                        <xsl:value-of select="@Host" />
                        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$separator" />            
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>         
    </xsl:element> 
</xsl:template>
```

Could you guys help me using an XSLT 1.0 processor?

Comment: Please show your current XSLT stylesheet.

Comment: Current XSLT added, many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to do a second set of Muenchian grouping here, because you also need to group on a combination of "User" and "Host" to get the distinct `Host` attribute for each user. So, you need a second key like so:

```
<xsl:key name="myKey2" match="Connection" use="concat(@User, '|', @Host)"/>
```

(Note that the pipe `|` could be anything here, just as long as it doesn't occur in either `User` or `Host`).

And then you use in your inner `xsl:for-each` like so:

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('myKey', @User)[count(. | key('myKey2', concat(@User, '|', @Host))[1]) = 1]">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="myKey" match="Connection" use="@User"/>
<xsl:key name="myKey2" match="Connection" use="concat(@User, '|', @Host)"/>
<xsl:variable name="separator" select="'|'"/>

<xsl:template match="Log1"> 
    <xsl:element name="Log2">       
        <xsl:for-each select="Connection[count(. | key('myKey', @User)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:sort select="@User" />
            <xsl:element name="Event">
                <xsl:attribute name="Name">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@User" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="Target">
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('myKey', @User)[count(. | key('myKey2', concat(@User, '|', @Host))[1]) = 1]">
                        <xsl:sort select="@Host" />
                        <xsl:value-of select="@Host" />
                        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$separator" />            
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>         
    </xsl:element> 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As a side note, there is no real need to use `xsl:element` to create elements with static names, just write the element out directly. For example

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="myKey" match="Connection" use="@User"/>
<xsl:key name="myKey2" match="Connection" use="concat(@User, '|', @Host)"/>
<xsl:variable name="separator" select="'|'"/>

<xsl:template match="Log1"> 
    <Log2>       
        <xsl:for-each select="Connection[count(. | key('myKey', @User)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:sort select="@User" />
            <Event Name="{@User}">
                <xsl:attribute name="Target">
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('myKey', @User)[count(. | key('myKey2', concat(@User, '|', @Host))[1]) = 1]">
                        <xsl:sort select="@Host" />
                        <xsl:value-of select="@Host" />
                        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$separator" />            
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </Event>
        </xsl:for-each>         
    </Log2> 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also note the use of attribute value templates in creating the `Name` attribute.

Comment: Hi Tim, I just tested your XSLT and it works like a charm! Many thanks!